# SSH from PowerShell - how to pass pasword in shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, powershell

How can I pass password in shortcut to PowerShell? I do know how to pass username - in terget field of this shortcut:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ssh remote.host.name
```

but not how to pass password.

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Do not use password to ssh, use a key pair.

Comment: I know about it, but for some reasons I need a password this time. Is there a way to pass it to shortcut?

Comment: Why you need to do that step? Please add the details in your question.